# Run jquery function after $.each has finished using promise

Tags: jquery, loops, each, promise

I have an each loop that pulls foursquare info. It looks similar to the following:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?search_string_here',    
 function(data) {
     $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){
          var content = foursquare stuff;
          $(content).appendTo("#fourSquare");
     });
});
```

I need to initiate a function after the each loop is finished. This works if placed after the each loop:

```
$( "#fourSquare" ).promise().done(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

I am not familiar with `promise` - the strange thing is that it works with ANY selector. Two Questions:

1) Is this the best way of going about an each callback?
2) What is the correct selector here? The each isnt iterating over already existing elements, so I am unsure of what to 'promise'

Comment: When used on an element, .promise gets a promise object that refers to a deferred object that resolves when all queued methods are complete, such as animations. It does not track ajax requests primarily because ajax requests are not directly linked to elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.getJSON` will return a promise that you can use.  This will be called *after* the callback.

```
var $ajax = $.getJSON('url', function(data){
    // your $.each
});

$ajax.done(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the promise returned by `getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON(...)
    .then(function() { $.each(...); })
    .then(function() { ... });
```